# HSP profile implementation?

Tags: bluetooth, headphones, bluetooth-profile

Currently I am writing an application that uses bluetoothctl (but not BlueZ).
Is it possible to use HSP/HFP profiles somehow?

I had googled a lot, but I didn't find any solution.

And would it be difficult to write a simple implementation? I saw BlueZ's source code, but it looks very complex and hardly understandable.

Comment: `bluetoothctl` is part of bluez. So what do you mean by "an application that uses bluetoothctl (but not BlueZ)"? HSP/HFP profiles are supported in bluez via the dbus interface. For examples written in python have a look at the simple-endpoint and test-hfp files in the [bluez test directory](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test).

Comment: @kaylum The system i write this app for uses BlueZ5. And as I know, BlueZ5 doesn't have HSP/HFP profiles. Please, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Yes you are wrong :-) Here is the official bluez5 [supported features list](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/supported-features.txt). It includes HFP and HSP.

Comment: @kaylum Wow, thats great, i'll try it. Thanks a lot.